# Epsilon delta of f(x)=1/x

Tags: limits

I want to prove the following:

$$\lim_{x\to x_1}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x_1},x_1\ne0$$.

when $x_1>0$:
$$\forall\epsilon>0:\\\left|f(x)-\frac{1}{x_1}\right|<\epsilon\implies\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_1}\right|<\epsilon\implies \left|x_1-x\right|<\epsilon\left|x\right|\left|x_1\right|\implies \left|x-x_1\right|<\epsilon\left|x\right|\left|x_1\right|$$

The problem is that I do not know what to choose for delta.
I thought about picking $δ=2|x1|$ but this have some problems ;/

Comment: look at this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference this time i edit your question

Answer (score 1):

Let's choose $\delta=\frac{|x_1|}{2}$ so:$$-\frac{|x_1|}{2}<x-x_1<\frac{|x_1|}{2}\\-\frac{|x_1|}{2}+x_1<x<\frac{|x_1|}{2}+x_1\\\text{for $x>0$ you have: }\frac1{|x|}<\frac1{-\frac{|x_1|}{2}+x_1}=\frac1{x_1-\frac{|x_1|}{2}}=\frac2{x_1}$$
now when $x>0$:$$ \frac{\left|x-x_1\right|}{|x|}<{\left|x-x_1\right|}{\frac{2}{x_1}}<\epsilon\left|x_1\right|\\\left|x-x_1\right|<\delta=\frac{\epsilon|x_1|x_1}{2}$$
so we have $\delta:=\min\left\{\frac{|x_1|}{2},\frac{\epsilon|x_1|x_1}{2}\right\}$

with similar way you can find $\delta$ for $x<0$

Comment: It seems so abstract that you chose $\delta = |x_1|/2$
Or something goings wrong and I cannot understand it ;/

Comment: @KwnstantinosNikoloutsos abstract? Maybe a little, but $\delta -\epsilon$ proofs are usually look like this when you are not taking a specific value. Try to use it for, let's say, $\lim\limits_{x\to1}\frac1x$ and maybe you'll feel more comfortable with that way. Some of them even choose pure numbers(look at the proof of $x^2$ at wiki)

Comment: I read the limits in spivak's book and I understood it.Thank youu!
@Holo

Answer (score 0):

Hint (for $x_1>0$):
$$\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_1}\right| < \epsilon\quad\Longleftrightarrow \quad \frac{-\epsilon x_1}{1+\epsilon x_1} < x-x_1 < \frac{\epsilon x_1}{1-\epsilon x_1}$$
so one could set
$$\delta(\epsilon) = \min\left(\frac{\epsilon x_1}{1+\epsilon x_1},\frac{\epsilon x_1}{|1-\epsilon x_1|}\right)>0.$$

Comment: I could not understand how you went from $|1/x-1/x_1|<\epsilon$ to the other 
inequality

Comment: $$\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_1}\right| < \epsilon \Rightarrow -\epsilon <\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x_1} < \epsilon \Rightarrow -\epsilon x_1 <\frac{x_1}{x}-1 < \epsilon x_1\Rightarrow 1-\epsilon x_1 <\frac{x_1}{x} < 1+\epsilon x_1\Rightarrow (1+\epsilon x_1)^{-1} <\frac{x}{x_1} < (1-\epsilon x_1)^{-1}\Rightarrow \ldots$$ and so on

Comment: How did you know that $1-\epsilon*x_1 > 0 $ .
Because you cannot say the following $-3<2<4 ==> 1/(-3)>1/2>1/4$

Comment: Fair point, you can get around that by differing between the cases $\epsilon<1/x_1$ and $\epsilon\geq 1/x_1$. For the second case you can pick an $\epsilon_0<1/x_1 \leq \epsilon$ and set $\delta(\epsilon):=\delta(\epsilon_0)$.

Comment: can please tell me if this solution is correct?
given $\epsilon > 0 $ and because the 1/x has this $ f(α)>f(β) <=> α<β$
We can pick as $\delta = min{(1/(x_1+\epsilon),1/(x_1-\epsilon))}$